# ajax returns empty result in ie10

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I'm using jquery ajax for my login page. It works fine in all browsers. I checked in ie. It also works except ie10. When I'm using this which returns empty ajax response. Is this my coding issue or browser issue? Kindly help me :)

my ajax code is,

```
$("#loading").show();   
    var postData=$("#frmLogin").serialize();

    $.ajax(
    {

        url : "ajax/ajax_formsubmit.php",
        type: "POST",
        data : postData,
        success:function(data)
        {   
            $("#loading").hide();   
            if(data=="Error"){
                $("#warning").show().html("Please provide valid login details!!!"); 
            }
            else if(data=="Success"){
                $("#success").show().html("Successfully Logined. Please wait...."); 
                window.location.href="user.php";
            }
        },
    });
```

Comment: Is the server response valid? If not, is the request correct? If both are true, then it's not the javascript's fault

Comment: try console out that what you get in ur response and let know us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this may be the ie10 compatibility issue. Add this code inside your  tag

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9" >
```

refer this [link](http://code.gishan.net/code/solution-to-ie10-ajax-problem/):